# Hadoop MapReduce iterate over input values of a reduce call

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm testing a simple mapreduce application, but I'm getting a little stuck trying to understand what happen when I iterate over input values of a reduce call.

This is the piece of code which behaves strangely..

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<E> values, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    Iterator<E> iterator = values.iterator();
    E first = (E)statesIter.next();

    while(statesIter.hasNext()){
        E state = statesIter.next();

        System.out.println(first.toString());
        // some other stuff
    }
    // some other stuff
}
```

so nothing strange.. except the fact that each println invocation actually prints a different string. So, every time I call the `next()` method, the object referenced by `first` changes.

So why this strange behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's somewhat counter-intuitive, but it's actually [documented in the API docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reducer.html#reduce%28K2,%20java.util.Iterator,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter%29) -- Hadoop reuses the keys / values, you should clone them if you want to keep them around.