# Reducer iterable value seems to be inconsistent in Java MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, iterator

I have the following code inside my reduce function. When I try to make a shallow copy using the CollectionUtils.addAll, the copy is unsuccessful; all the items  will have the reference of the LAST item instead of the other items in the iterator.

Here's the code from my Reducer:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<ArrayListWritable<Writable>> values, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<ArrayListWritable<Writable>> listOfWordPairs = new ArrayList<ArrayListWritable<Writable>>();

    // CollectionUtils.addAll(listOfWordPairs, values.iterator());
    // listOfWordPairs seems to all be the last item in the iterator

    Iterator<ArrayListWritable<Writable>> iter = values.iterator();

    // Manually do the copy
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        // listOfWordPairs.add(iter.next()); 
        //Same behaviour as CollectionUtils.addAll()

        listOfWordPairs.add(new ArrayListWritable<Writable>(iter.next())); 
        //Only working way to do it -> deep copy :(
        }
    }
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? I can see that if MR implemented it this way it can save a pretty big chunk of memory, but there seems to be some magic going on here to make it happen. I'm new to MR so hopefully the question isn't too stupid...

Here's  my MAP code for people who are interested

```
@Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          Map<String, HMapStFW> stripes = new HashMap<>();

          List<String> tokens = Tokenizer.tokenize(value.toString());

          if (tokens.size() < 2) return;
          context.getCounter(StripesPmiEnums.TOTALENTRIES).increment(tokens.size());

          for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size() && i<40; i++) {
            for (int j = 0;j<tokens.size() && j<40;j++){
                if (j == i)
                    continue;
                //Make Stripe if doesn't exist
                if (!stripes.containsKey(tokens.get(i))){
                    HMapStFW newStripe = new HMapStFW();
                    stripes.put(tokens.get(i), newStripe);
                }

                HMapStFW stripe = stripes.get(tokens.get(i));
                if (stripe.containsKey(tokens.get(j))){
                    stripe.put(tokens.get(j), stripe.get(tokens.get(j))+1.0f);
                }else{
                    stripe.put(tokens.get(j), 1.0f);
                }
            }
          }

          for (String word1 : stripes.keySet()) {
            TEXT.set(word1);
            context.write(TEXT, stripes.get(word1));
          }
        }
```

And also the ArrayListWritable is available here
https://github.com/lintool/tools/blob/master/lintools-datatypes/src/main/java/tl/lin/data/array/ArrayListWritable.java

Comment: It appears to me you override the writable interface methods can you share that code along with mapper code.

Comment: @siddhartha jain I added it to the OP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop MapReduce iterate over input values of a reduce call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976981/hadoop-mapreduce-iterate-over-input-values-of-a-reduce-call)

Answer (score 0):

this is because the iterator work different in the reducer. Short answer, you have to clone your object while you iterate the iterator

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    //this is correct
    listOfWordPairs.add(new ArrayListWritable<Writable>(iter.next())); 

    }
}
```

take a look to the following link, it is very well explained

https://cornercases.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/hadoop-object-reuse-pitfall-all-my-reducer-values-are-the-same/